# How can C# code check if a Context Connection (an in-process-only connection,) can be used?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, sqlclr

I have written a C# library assembly. It is in a NUGET and contains functions that can be called both from T-SQL scripts (CLR-integration) and from other .net-code. I like the code to be able to check what context it is run in. That is, if a Context Connection (in-process-only connection) is available or not. (If it is I will an entry to a logtable when an exception occours.)

How can a method in a C#-class best determine if the code is executed “in-process” on a SQL Server?  If a SqlConnection("context connection=true") can be used? (I do not like to call SqlConnection("context connection=true") and get an System.NotSupportedException if the code is not run in an SQL Server.)

Answer (score 1):

You can check [`SqlContext.IsAvailable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlcontext.isavailable).

Comment: **Thanks**. The problem is perhaps that I'm using _.NET Standard_ / _.NET Core_ and that I **can't find the SqlContext Class** or any Nuget for these frameworks that contains System.Data.dll. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places?